# How to restrict CSS style to apply to a particular SVG only?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have several SVGs that I would like to style using CSS. However, the styles seem to be applied across SVGs.

Unfortunately, I cannot use classes on SVG elements or a iframe.

Is there a way to apply styles to a particular SVG only?

Here is an example where differenty styles are used within SVG but the second applies to the first aparently.

```
<svg>
  <style>
    line {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>

<svg>
  <style>
    line {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmmyEe

**Edit**

Maybe this is a better example:

```
<svg>
  <style>
    .colored {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="colored" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>

<svg>
  <style>
    .colored {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="colored" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>
```

I would like to be able to let the user edit the style of each of these SVGs so that the user needs to know only what a class does for all the SVGs. If I would use different classes, like "colored1" and "colored2" or so, that would make it trickier for the user which I want to avoid.

Comment: If you can't target it individually then the answer is no. There's a reason we use classes and IDs and you've just found out what it is,

Comment: Unfortunately scoped CSS has been removed from the specs, so in short you can't: any `<style>` tags in the document will be hoisted to the global scope.

Comment: by the way, why not applying the style directly to the elements as inline ?

Comment: Why exactly can't you add an ID or a CLASS?

Comment: @Paulie_D I could understand why it is important that classes defined on the higher scope apply accross the board. But in my case, it just makes it impossible use styles just to style separate SVGs which makes using styles for styling SVGs very tricky.

Comment: @Terry I wasn't aware there was a spec suggested for it. Too bad it was abandoned then...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Classes are so much more flexible than directly applying styles.

Comment: Classes & IDs are **hooks** to target many and/or specific elements as required...this seems like the ideal place for them, I don't understand your resistance.

Comment: @Yorick I am creating several SVGs for export. The user can then edit the classes of each SVG manually. I would like to have only one set of classes the user would have to understand in order to make changes to the separate SVGs.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know that my case extremely simplified. But I have SVGs that use several elements with the same class and or share different classes. So, I already make use of benefits of classes. However, I would like to use the same class name for different SVGs because the user can manually edit them. But having a different class name for every SVG would make this much more cumbersome for the user.

Comment: If your SVGs are different then how else would you identify them? If you want to style sub-elements inside the SVG then that's a different issue. Perhaps providing a **better example** of what you are trying to do would be useful.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. I tried to give a better example. But it might just be impossible. This is really strange. I thought CSS becomes more and more common in styling SVGs. But if one would use two SVGs with CSS styles on a single site that would spell trouble if some classes are used differently in the SVGs. So, SVGs cannot be considered as standalone as other pictures one uses. That's unfortunate, at least for my use case.

Comment: @Paulie_D Here is another example. Say, you have a library that creates SVG code for a website. However, you cannot be sure what the resulting SVG will look like since it might be that (1) the user already uses the same classnames on her page, or (2) the user already uses another SVG created by the library but with different values, for example colors.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how your SVG are placed within your HTML and **there is no way** to add ID or classes, you can rely on `nth-of-type`/`nth-child` to restrict your rules to only one element:

```html
<svg>
  <style>
    svg:nth-of-type(1) line {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>

<svg>
  <style>
    svg:nth-of-type(2) line {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>
```

And the above is the same as using external CSS:

```css
svg:nth-of-type(1) line {
  stroke: red;
}

svg:nth-of-type(2) line {
  stroke: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg>

<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>

<svg>

  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>
```

---

Another idea is to use CSS variable that you define on your SVG (or on a wrapper) as inline style:

```css
line {
  stroke: var(--s,#000);
}

}
```

```html
<svg style="--s:red">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>
<span style="--s:green">
<svg >
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>
</span>
```

Comment: More likely `nth-of-type` and i doubt the structure will permit this to work properly.

Comment: The problem is that need the style both inside the SVG and cannot have different selectors...

Answer (score 1):

You could target them using `nth-child` or a similar selector:

```css
svg:nth-child(1) line {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <style>
    line {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>

<svg>
  <style>
    line {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>
```

If you can't do this, then just wrap it in an element and add a class to that, which you can then use to target the svg

Or you could use inline styles in your svgs (but I'm guessing if you can't add classes, you can't edit the svg)