# How to embed standalone SVG code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a javascript library with SVG output. For simplicity, say

```
line(color).
```

so that

```
line('red')
```

outputs

```
<svg>
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>
```

The problem is that if I try to add several of these SVGs with different color arguments to my page the `.color` class gets overwritten so that only the last definition of the class is applied to all SVGs. Like here

```
<svg>
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>
<svg>
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100">
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyyvxE

One way around this is to embed the SVGs in `iframe`s. However, I read that iframes are to be used only sparely since they are computationally expensive. Maybe there is some way to turn the SVC code with JavaScript into a data URI and use it in an `object` tag? Or how to best use such different SVGs in a website?

Comment: fix the library so it creates unique class names. Performance test iframes rather than relying on random stuff you read that may be wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. Unfortunately, I cannot fix the library. So that is no possibility. So, you suggest iframes are not so bad after all. I guess one other problem with I frames is that they don't nicely fit the dimensions of the SVG, right?

Comment: @RobertLongson I hoped I did. Or at least that was my intention. However, I was also particularly interested in that in relation to SVG code. I thought, maybe there are certain alternatives that fit particularly well with displaying SVGs. I'd be very happy about suggestions.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is in using either an iframe or an object tag (other than unfounded reluctance). I suggest abandoning the javascript library too, its clearly not fit for purpose.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. So, the problems with iframes not easily fitting the dimensions of the embedded code and object tags needing a URI rather than plain SVG code are non problems. Okay, then I must have misunderstoods those tags and have to do more reading on them. I'll suggest to close this post then. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I don't know, you havent provided any examples of any problems, other than the terrible javascript library, the answer to which is not to use it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried to mention the problem with the object tag (that they need a URI which I don't have). And mentioned in the comments the problem with iframe dimensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170896/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-daniel).

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295266/how-to-restrict-css-style-to-apply-to-a-particular-svg-only

Comment: @TemaniAfif This is my attempt to make my question more precise... probaly I still didn't succeed...

Comment: your question was already clear and the answers also : It's not possible what you want as you can read here and in the other question

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess my main problem was that I wanted something that isn't possible. After that it is quite hard to ask for "something very similar"...

Comment: @RobertLongson Finally managed to get it working. Thanks for your helpful suggestions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the helpful discussion with Robert Longson, I found at least two ways to get SVG standalones for the SVG code above: using an `img` tag, which makes the SVG behave like a bitmap, I believe, and using an `object` tag. Details below.

Either, use img and just set the SVG code as data:

```
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px">
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>' alt="" />
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px">
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>' alt="" />
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oddKyZ

**Note!** the data string is a bit less forgiving than plain html in browsers. I had to add the missing slash when closing the line element.

Alternatively, one can use an `object` like this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px">
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: red;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>'>
</object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="100px" width="100px">
  <style>
    .color {
      stroke: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <line class="color" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"/>
</svg>'>
</object>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/errqLY

**Note!** There are some characters that at least some browsers cannot interpret in URI's. For example, firefox does not allow hash (`#`) which is common in SVG `url()` definitions and has to be replaced by `%23`. I guess a save way would be to use JavaScript `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the SVG correctly.